# A "A <Router> may have only one child element" this is the error I am getting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am completely new to React I am trying to wrap my App in Router but I get this error I wrapped it in the div but still not working can someone help me Please ?
Sorry if its irrelevant or stupid question.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import routes from'./routes';
import {Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} >
       <div>
           <App/>
       </div>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I use 1 route it works but when i put 2 it doesn't the error is here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import AddDetails from './components/AddDetails';
import ShowDetails from'./components/ShowDetails';
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <NavBar/>
                <BrowserRouter>

                   <Switch>
                        <Route exact={true} path='/' render={() => (
                            <div>
                                <AddDetails />
                            </div>
                        )}/>
                        <Route exact={true} path='details' render={() => (
                            <div>
                                <ShowDetails />
                            </div>
                        )}/>
                    </Switch>
               </BrowserRouter>

           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: No effect same error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: A <Router> may have only one child element

Comment: I can clearly see that `Router` has only one child. Maybe caching issues? Or the bug is somewhere in your code?

Comment: This is because `<BrowserRouter>` can only have one child. See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={history} routes={routes} >
     <App/>
  </Router>),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

As per your update, you should wrap your Router with a div or you may use switch:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
      <Route exact={true} path='/' render={() => (
              <div>
                  <AddDetails />
              </div>
          )}/>
      <Route exact={true} path='details' render={() => (
                  <div>
                     <ShowDetails />
                  </div>
              )}/>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP's code isn't working. Also there isn't really a difference between this and OP in terms of the error.

Comment: @SaifKhan it seems you have issue with routes. Show us routes code.

Comment: Check it now yes i check the mistake was there ma bad

Comment: @SaifKhan Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add react router `Switch` to render only one child component

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';


<BrowserRouter>

<Switch>
      <Route exact={true} path='/' render={() => (
              <div>
                  <AddDetails />
              </div>
          )}/>
              <Route exact={true} path='details' render={() => (
                  <div>
                     <ShowDetails />
                  </div>
              )}/>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Let me know if the issue still persists

Comment: It got resolved thank you, can I ask you for your little more help ?

Comment: Sure. Please feel free to ask

Comment: I added 2 routes in my app path= "/" and path="details" but when I click on the link of / it works but the link on details doesn't.

Comment: Add ‘exact’ in your first route and read about it too. It woll solve the issue

Comment: I have added exact = { true } in both of them

Comment: Please have you added switch ? otherwise issue won’t resolve to render only one child

Comment: I would recommend you to post another question with updated code and state your problem. So more user would be there help you out and post updated code there. As this question has already accepted answer so users won’t know about your current issue.

Comment: Can you check it now please ?

Comment: Okay I was doing a very silly mistake and i realized it when I posted the code in the question and It was very stupid that I deleted it. Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove routes prop and pass your routes as child of your div/Switch.

Check the quick start:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/quick-start.md